# Using machine-vision to measure surface roughness

Tags: computer-vision

I have to build a machine vision sytem to measure the surface roughness of steel using a single camera and light source. I would like a few ideas on how to choose the best camera for such a project.

Comment: "best camera" requires to know the goals of your system.

Comment: We want to measure surface roughness, dross, kerf-width etc of steel. These features have a range which varies from 0.2micron to 3mm